# Would it be possible to grep two specific things of output?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am using transmission-remote to view the list of running torrents.

When using `transmission-remote -l` results in following:

```
ID  Done    Have  ETA     Up    Down  Ratio Status Name

1   100%    10GB  Done    0.0   0.0   0.0   Idle   Torrent

Sum: 15.91 GB    0.0     0.0
```

Would I be able to grep out the percentage and the name of the torrent?

At the moment I have the following:
`transmission-remote -l | grep -o -P '.{0,3}%'`

This returns the `100%`

Comment: Use awk to extract field no.2 and from no.9 to end of line. I guess you could also `cut -f 2,9-` if you squeezed all consecutive blanks into single tabs via `tr`...

Comment: I'm not sure about how awk works. Are they indexed in a table? Would awk be able to extract the fields? There are only space between the columns?

Comment: `awk` operates on fields separated by one or more blanks - but you can specify the field separator - it's _very flexible_. It's all in the manual...

Comment: Thanks god, you have saved my evening. Lovely to learn new commands!

Comment: grep will always output each match on a separate new line. there is no way to output multiple `-o` matches from the same input line onto the same output line. you could try to `sed s/…//` away all the parts of a line you don't care about, and even `sed s/…(…)…(…)…/\2\1/` to rearrange the interresting parts.

Comment: You could use `cut`, `awk` or `sed` (they get progressively more complex and powerful in the order listed. `grep` was designed to just find matches, not reformat / edit / change.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to do it with grep, but there is simple solution with `awk`.

For only first torrent in list:

```
transmission-remote -l | awk '{if (NR == 3) {print $2, $9}} '
```

For all torrents (if each one has blank line before, if it isn't true replace `i += 2` to `i++`):

```
transmission-remote -l | awk '{lines[NR]=$2 " " $9} END {for (i = 3; i < NR; i += 2) print lines[i]} '
```

In second case we put lines into array and use for-loop for printing them when input is read.

Answer (score 0):

```
head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | 
sed -re 's/[[:blank:]]+/\t/g' | 
cut -f 2,9
```

This will:

- select 3 record (line)
- convert spaces to single tab, (preprocessing for cut)
- select fields 2 and 9

`cut` was not powerful enough alone, so I used head and tail to select the line (there seemed to be nothing distinctive to `grep` on), and then a simple `sed` recipe to pre-precess ready for `cut`.